# DFP Multi-request - Initiation Time

Tags: google-dfp, double-click-advertising

Am using DFP for rendering ads in a website. In DFP i have configured multiple ads vendors.For the purpose of reporting i need to save when request to each slot is generated. How can i find when the request for the each slot is generated . Am using DFP Multi-request mode.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use SlotRenderEndedEvent.

Docs: https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletageventsslotrenderendedevent

```
googletag.cmd.push( function() {
    googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', function(data) {
        //saving data..
        console.log(new Date().getTime());
        console.log(data.creativeId);
    });
});
```